# Высота таблицы на все оставшееся место

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

В следующем каркасе:

```
<div id="menu"></div>
<table style="height:100%;>
 <!-- content -->
</table>
<div id="prompt"></div>
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы menu и prompt имели фиксированную высоту и были расположены относительно таблицы сверху и снизу соответственно. А таблица занимала по высоте все оставшееся место. В данном случае высота равна высоте родительского блока.

Как осуществить определение высоты по оставшемся месту?
Пока, как вариант, сделал в таблице padding'и сверху и снизу, и соответствующие им отрицательные margin'ы. С виду - не костыль, но может есть другие способы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать без отрицательных **margin**'ов, если есть возможно добавить для родительского контейнера **position** отличный от **static**. Тогда для **#menu** и **#prompt** добавляем **postion: absolute**, а для таблицы добавляем **padding**'и нужной высоты.

Пример http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbNWMO

Но вариант лучше - это сделать **#menu** и **#prompt** частью таблицы, например: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbBJNm. Здесь не будет зависимости от высоты контента #menu и #prompt, плюсом еще вертикальное позиционирование.

Вариант лучше предыдущего - это переписать на блочную верстку (**display: table\table-row\table-cell**) или flex.

Comment: вариант с внесением их в таблицу рассматривал, но тогда они напрямую зависят от количества колонок, которые были не определены, тогда лишь оставалось бы объединить ячейки, но это уже лишнее

Comment: Если контент заранее не известен, то лучше будет сделать вариант с display: table - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxQjpw. Теперь #menu и #prompt могут быть любой высоты, можно добавить вертикальное позиционирование, а так же нет зависимости от контента.

Answer (score 0):

для html,body задать `height:100%;` и потом уже вашему блоку `height:100%;`